# Checking if multiple rows exists when populating Data Table

Tags: c#

I'm trying to populate a Data Table with a range of years to be used in a Data List. My application has five lists on the page and I have buttons to scroll through the years: 1995, 1996, 1997 and so on.
However, if year 1997 does not exist in the database I get an error in my application: `There is no row at position 2`. How can I prevent this? `if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)` checks that data exists but how do I check that data exists before setting the value of the other strings (SecondYear, ThirdYear, FourthYear, FifthYear)

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()))
        {
            FirstYear = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[1][0].ToString()))
        {
            SecondYear = dt.Rows[1][0].ToString();
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[2][0].ToString()))
        {
            ThirdYear = dt.Rows[2][0].ToString();
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[3][0].ToString()))
        {
            FourthYear = dt.Rows[3][0].ToString();
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[4][0].ToString()))
        {
            FifthYear = dt.Rows[4][0].ToString();
        }
    }
```

This does not work:

```
if (dt.Rows[1][0].Count > 0)
        {
            SecondYear = dt.Rows[1][0].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: when you use if (dt.Rows[1][0].Count > 0), which line is throwing exception?is it SecondYear = dt.Rows[1][0].ToString(); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the nr. of rows are larger than or equal to the year row you are checking.

```
if(dt.Rows.Count >= 1) 
   SecondYear = dt.Rows[1][0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of indexers, please try to use DataRowExtensions (or DataSetExtensions) as below

```
var o1 = dt.Rows[1].Field<string>(0);
```

or more readable using column name:

```
var o2 = dt.Rows[1].Field<string>("columnName");
```